# How can I run a python project (has many file with .py) which downloaded from Github?

Tags: python, github

I am just a newbie at Python and have intention to learn abut class from others authors.
I am facing the issue with running their code.
How to reproduce the issue:
Step 1: Download a game at link: https://github.com/TkhiienLok/Snake-Pygame
Step 2: With many files (some files with .py, some of images, even .txt file), I don't know how can I run it (these file) to observe the result.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Consider making a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the section [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-as) before posting another question.

Comment: Sorry for any inconvenient!
I will read all the session carefully before posting. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Open console in folder Snake-Pygame and type

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

This will install required packages. Then type

```
python main.py
```

to run your game.